# Showing all the packages for a cruisecontrol project

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a cruisecontrol.net project currently being built, and a package created for it using the package node in the publishers config section.  For each build I see the zip file being created and placed in my directory, however, through the webdashboard, or cctray, when I look at the packages list it only shows the latest.  I’m not sure if it is possible, but I want to see all of them – i.e. the complete history of builds.

It looks like it is possible by using the “single” node… as defined here:
http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Package%20Publisher.html

However, the documentation doesn’t look up to date, as that causes this error:
[CCNet Server:ERROR] Exception: Unused node detected: true

My config is as follows:

```
<package>
  <name>MyProject</name>
  <always>true</always>
  <flatten>true</flatten>
  <!--<single>true</single>-->
  <baseDirectory>D:\Builds\MyProject\Trunk\Source\bin\Release</baseDirectory>
  <files>
    <file>*.dll</file>
    <file>*.config</file>
    <file>*.exe</file>
  </files>
</package>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see "single" listed in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed in version 1.6. Both CCTray and the web dashboard now list the files from all builds. Each file includes corresponding build number.